# How to solve temperature readings in a faulty thermometers using correct thermometer readings?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, quadratics, linear-programming

Here is the context. I have a infrared thermometer and a digital thermometer. My daughter (2 years old) is afraid of anything that looks like a syringe, for obvious reasons. (Please don't judge my parenting skills, though :)) So, we can only use the infrared thermometer most of the time and it doesn't give the correct temperature. So, I tried to find a formula to be able to be able to match the readings with the digital (correct) one. What I did was, took two different person temperature readings (all readings are in F) and tried solving the quadratic equations. For 98.3 and 99 degrees the faulty one gives 99.1 and 100.4 degrees, respectively. So, the equations I derived are:

```
98.3X - 99.1Y  = 0 &
99X   - 100.4Y = 0
___________________
0.7X  - 1.3Y   = 0

X = (1.3/0.7)Y
```

Substituting the value of X in one of the equation:

```
99(1.3/0.7)Y - 100.4Y = 0
Y = 1/83.457 = 0.011982
```

Substituting value of Y, we get value of X:

```
99X - 100.4*0.011982 = 0
X = 0.012152
```

Now we should be able to use these X & Y values to get the correct reading for a wrong reading.
if Tw = 97.3 (w stands for wrong) then correct reading Tc should be:

```
Tc = Tw*(Y/X)
   = 97.3*0.986010533
   = 95.93
```

But the actual reading is 96.9.
Have I got this completely wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Let the faulty temperature be $Y$ and the correct temperature be $X$, then assuming a linear model, we have

$ Y = a X + b $

Substituting the two pairs of temperatures that we have

$ 99.1 = a (98.3) + b $

$ 100.4 = a (99) + b $

Which solves to $a = \dfrac{13}{7} , b = - \dfrac{2921}{35} $

From which

$X = \dfrac{1}{a} (Y - b) = \dfrac{7}{13} (Y + \dfrac{2921}{35} )$

Plug in $Y = 97.3$, you get

$X = \dfrac{7}{13} ( 97.3 + \dfrac{2921}{35} ) = 97.33 $

Since the actual temperature measured is $96.9$, it means our linear model is not $100\%$ correct, and also that we need more decimals in the our readings of the actual correct temperature and the faulty one.  However, note that the percent difference between the calculated temperature and the measured one is

$ \dfrac{ 97.33 - 96.9 }{96.9} \times 100 \% = 0.44 \% $

which is a very good percent error.

Comment: That 0.44 'percent error' is not very meaningful, as the zero (with respect to which you take 96.9 in denominator) is arbitrary here.

Comment: The zero is not arbitrary, it is the zero Fahrenheit, a well defined temperature.

Comment: Yes, the zero of the scale is arbitrary, just like the zero of the Celsius scale. Do the same linear interpolation in Celsius, Rankine or Réaumur degrees and you'll get precisely the same corresponding results – but the percent error will be different. Just because, and precisely because, those scales have incompatible, arbitrarily chosen, zeros.

Comment: LexiBelleFan You and @golden_ratio above have put me in the right direction. But gathering more points would be difficult. Let me see what can I do. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, but we're talking about a specific scale here which is the Fahrenheit scale, so the results are meaningful, because the scale is not arbitrary, it is precisely and exactly the Fahrenheit scale and nothing else.

Comment: When you raise your hat by 10 centimeters above your head, it might be approx 100% rise if you measure its height relative to the tip of your nose; or something like 5.5% if you measure the height relative to the groung where you're standing; or just about 0.001% if you measure it relative to the mean sea level while standing on the peak of Mount Everest. That's because the choice of the 'zero level' is arbitrary. Of course you _can_ calculate the percentage quantity – but due to the arbitrary choice of the zero, that percentage _is_ quite meaningless.

Comment: @CiaPan The error percentage I calculated is a measure of how close the two numbers are, when one of the two numbers is taken as a reference.  The reference number here is the actual correct reading of the temperature, so the percentage will indicate how close the number calculated is to the reference number.  It's a comparison between two numerical values.  The bigger the error percentage, the more different and farther the two numbers are, and vice versa.  If the reference number is 50 then numbers in the range [49.5, 50.5] are within 1% of 'error' from it.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting your three data points (correct temperature $C$ on x axis and wrong temperature $W$ on y axis) shows a nonlinear relation (check the slopes):
[image]

Therefore, I would be interested in gathering more data points to determine a suitable relation. I would also be interested in determining if the wrong one gives consistent readings.

If you are interested in predicting $W$ from $C$ with a linear model, one approach is to run a regression. More data would be better for this (and splitting it into training and testing data would be even better), but your three points gives a prediction equation of approximately

$$\hat W=1.449C-43.163$$

Comment: Wow! Why didn't I think of this? You have so rightly pointed it out. I work in machine learning and still I thought that this would be linear. Nevertheless, I have the right path. But the problem would be to get gather more data points (readings). Thank you so much.

Comment: @Rabindra no prob!